# How can I fade in changing words with .html?

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, words

I am trying to make the transition smoothly. The html is changing but I want it to look smoother. Does anyone know how to do this?

My code:

```
var words = ["Leergierige", "Enthousiaste", "vooruitstrevende", "innovatieve"];
var i = -1;

function randomWord(){
  //var randomId = document.getElementById("random-word");

  setInterval(function(){
    i++

  $("#random-word").html(words[i]).fadeIn("slow");

   if (i === 3){
    i = -1;
  }
}, 2000);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fadeOut` the previous words and then `fadeIn` the next word.

```
$("#random-word").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).html(words[i]).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tw52uzsm/)

Comment: Excellent!  I found `fadeTo` was slightly better for my needs as I didn't want the area to totally vanish: http://jsfiddle.net/28s9qfeb/4/.